# Rails + ActiveStorage problem when starting server = undefined method `has_one_attached'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I'm having a problem with a specific model. When I start my Ruby on Rails server `rails s` I get an error which says `undefined method`has_one_attached'`. Here's a strange thing:

If I comment out `has_one_attached :avatar` and start the server, it starts fine. Then I can uncomment `has_one_attached :avatar`, save the file and load the application, ActiveStorage functions.

But I don't want to have to comment out all active storage functions each time I start the server.

**Rails version = 5.2.1**

**Ruby version = 2.4.4**

Here's the model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_person_name

  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  # For reasons I can't understand. This doesn't work here. I'm developing it in organizations for the time being.
  has_one_attached :avatar
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations
end
```

Here's the application.rb file:

```
require_relative 'boot'
require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module *ProjectName*
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    config.generators do |g|
      g.orm                 :active_record
      g.template_engine     :erb
      g.test_framework      false
      g.stylesheets         false
      g.javascripts         false
      g.helper              false
      g.scaffold_stylesheet false
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the Error Message:

```
$ rails s
/Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/pry-rails-0.3.6/lib/pry-rails/prompt.rb:36: warning: constant Pry::Prompt::MAP is deprecated
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `has_one_attached' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  has_person_name
    from /Users/silverSheep/Desktop/code/withBetter/projectName/app/models/user.rb:3:in `<class:User>'
    from /Users/silverSheep/Desktop/code/withBetter/projectName/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:472:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:657:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:471:in `load_file'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:369:in `block in require_or_load'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:352:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:46:in `block in require_or_load'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:45:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:506:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `block in load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:57:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:193:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/silverSheep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-

...(shortened for brevity)....

    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: error seems to be on line 3 which is `rolify`

Comment: Commenting out rolify doesn't change the error...

Thank you for taking a look @emaillenin

Comment: Have you generated the migrations necessary for ActiveStorage?
You can do it by executing the following in the terminal: `rails active_storage:install:migrations`, thereafter `rails db:migrate`

Comment: Thank you @timbillstrom, but yeah... I've already done that. The weird part is that it's working fine for another (named "Organizations") model.

The server will start with `has_one_attached :avatar` commented out of the `User.rb` model file. If I uncomment and save after the server has started, ActiveStorage works for the User model then.

The problem is I can't start the server with `has_one_attached :avatar` in active code of the User model.

Comment: @iarobinson , if you're connected to a small database for development (with no crucial data, the following command will completely remove you database), I'd try to drop the database, and run the migrations(s) once again. I've encountered the same issue a while ago, too bad I can't recall my exact approach. Hint: `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Run `rails active_storage:install` and add the following to the *config/environments/development.rb* file to store the files locally:
`config.active_storage.service = :local`.

Also make sure to add the new parameter to the permitted ones to the *application_controller.rb*:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:avatar])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:avatar])
  end
```

And do not forget to do the migration for the new generated tables from active storage with `rails db:migrate`.